# Dovecot + Roundcube cannot login by webmail

Tags: postfix-mta, dovecot, roundcube

I have postfix + Dovecot + roundcube set up on a Ubuntu 14.04.
I can correctly send and receive email for my domain name using Thunderbird.
I correctly connect to my IMAP and POP 3 server using Thunderbird using STARTTLS.

But I can't connect using Webmail Roundcude. When I try to connect using `contact@domain.com` I get this log from mail.log:

```
Jan 17 16:59:44 vps232808 dovecot: imap-login: Disconnected (auth failed, 1 attempts in 5 secs): user=<contact@domain.com>, method=PLAIN, rip=51.255.204.45, lip=51.255.204.45, TLS, session=<tkBRuYkphQAz/8wt>
```

contact is also a system user.
When I connect with just contact as login, I could log but get the page

> " SERVICE CURRENTLY NOT AVAILABLE! Error No. [500]"

Answer (score 0):

This depends a little on your setup, but if you are logging in with a system user, don't use the email but simply the user name to log in.  Instead of `john@example.com` just use `john.

The mail address would be the correct choice if it were setup as a virtual alias, but it sounds like this is not the case here.